# Finding all the variables that give the highest Adjusted R squared value

Tags: python, pandas, linear-regression, statsmodels

I have a dataframe which stores different variables. I'm using OLS linear regression and using all of the variables to predict the 'price' column.

```
import pandas as pd
import statsmodels.api as sm

data = {'accommodates':[2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 6, 8, 4, 3, 2],
        'bedrooms':[1, 2, 1, 1, 3, 4, 2, 2, 2, 3],
        'instant_bookable':[1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1],
        'availability_365':[123, 3, 33, 14, 15, 16, 3, 41, 61, 74],
        'minimum_nights':[3, 12, 1, 4, 6, 7, 2, 3, 6, 10],
        'beds':[2, 2, 3, 4, 1, 5, 6, 2, 3, 2],
        'price':[59, 234, 15, 162, 56, 42, 28, 52, 22, 31]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['accommodates', 'bedrooms', 'instant_bookable', 'availability_365',
                                   'minimum_nights', 'beds', 'price'])
```

I have a for loop which calculates the Adjusted R squared value for each variable:

```
fit_d = {}

for columns in [x for x in df.columns if x != 'price']:
    
    Y = df['price']

    X = df[columns]

    X = sm.add_constant(X)

    model = sm.OLS(Y,X, missing = 'drop').fit()
    
    fit_d[columns] = model.rsquared
    

fit_d
```

How can I modify my code in order to find the combination of variables that give the largest Adjusted R squared value? Ideally the function would find the variable with the largest adj. R squared value first, then using the 1st variable iterate with the remaining variables to get 2 variables that give the highest value, then 3 variables etc. until the value cannot be increased further. I'd like the output to be something like

```
Best variables: {'accommodates, 'availability', 'bedrooms'}
```

Comment: Are you sure it is a good way to go with: better 1st variable then only look for combination with this variable. The problem I see is that let's say the best R is for accommodates, then the score does not increase by adding any other columns. but maybe using the combination of 'availability' and 'bedrooms' would be higher R even if individually they had lower R than accommodates. so your final solution would not be optimal. does it make sense?

Comment: Yes that makes perfect sense, that wouldn't be ideal. But for the sake of this context I'd like to do it even if it's sub-optimal. But as you've brought it up, I would be curious about the more optimal way to go about it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a "brute force way" to do all possible `combinations` (from `itertools`) of different length to find the variables with higher R value. The idea is to do 2 loops, one for the number of variables to try, and one for all the combinations with the number of variables.

```
from itertools import combinations

# all possible columns for X
cols = [x for x in df.columns if x != 'price']
# define Y as same accross the loops
Y = df['price']
# define result dictionary
fit_d = {}

# loop for any length of combinations
for i in range(1, len(cols)+1):
    # loop for any combinations with length i
    for comb in combinations(cols, i):
        # Define X from the combination
        X = df[list(comb)]
        X = sm.add_constant(X)
        # perform the OLS opertion
        model = sm.OLS(Y,X, missing = 'drop').fit()
        # save the rsquared in a dictionnary
        fit_d[comb] = model.rsquared

# extract the key for the max R value
key_max = max(fit_d, key=fit_d.get)

print(f'Best variables {key_max} for a R-value of {round(fit_d[key_max], 5)}')
# Best variables ('accommodates', 'bedrooms', 'instant_bookable', 'availability_365', 'minimum_nights', 'beds') for a R-value of 0.78506
```